# What does this name mean in pinyin/english?

Tags: translation, traditional-characters, pinyin, names

i'd appreciate it a lot if someone could tell me!

id like to know what this name means in pinyin, as well as english.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's a person's name, written in Traditional Chinese:

> 陳苡瑄

> Chén Yǐxuān

Answer (score 1):

The most important word in this name is "瑄", which is defined as an "ornamental piece of jade"

The word in the middle, "苡", is plantago, a type of small herb seed. This word can't be translated literally, rather should be associated with the words - plain, mild and good, through "聯想"和"意會".

Combined, the parents of the girl/lady, or the person gave the name, wised her grows up to be as pretty as jade, and posses good/smooth/mild personality.

Answer (score 0):

The name is not common. `陈` is very common family name, but `苡瑄` is not common. I think it is just about something precious plants and precious jade

Comment: so people would call them yixuan right? since chen is the family name i assume

Comment: @sophiexx That's right, or when getting even closer with the person, could call her "xuanxuan"

Answer (score 0):

There is no meaning for this name. just a fashion nowadays.

e.g.

- 国庆，秋艳:  naming style for 1950~60 people
- 小明，洋洋   naming style for 1970-1980 people
- 逸轩，艺轩，艺璇，昊然  naming style for 1990, 2000+ people.

and this is the joke for `Yi Xuan`, `Hao Ran` names:

[image]

refer to: https://www.sohu.com/a/270263294_774807